# Why does this jQuery not work in IE but in every other browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My question is why this code is working in all browsers except of IE function. In the other browsers it works.

if (phrases.indexOf(currentPhrase)) phrases.splice(phrases.indexOf(currentPhrase), 1);

Comment: Does IE give you any kind of JavaScript Error Messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that IE is caching the request (since it's through `GET`).  You can fix this in a bunch of ways including cache-control on the server side or using `POST` instead.  jQuery's `.load()` is a bit annoying in that you have to use an object as data to indicate you want a `POST` request and use a string for `GET` instead of allowing you to set an explicit request.

Comment: I found a trick to GET another variable like date(), is something like this you are referring to ?

Comment: Also, how do I make a POST request instead of this one ?

Comment: @kotsirokolos, yes, sending the datetime should work too.  You can make it POST by changing the data (second argument if there are three) to an object instead of a string or using `.post()`